# How to attach the second next process with lldb

Tags: lldb

Is is possible to let `lldb` to attach to the 2nd new process of some executable? We could attach the next new process of some executable with

```
attach -w -n "/path/to/executable"
```

But now an action will launch a pair of instances of some executable, I want to only attach to the  2nd process.

Answer (score 1):

lldb doesn't have a "wait for second next version" primitive.  But using the SB API's it would be pretty easy to write a Python command that does an attach wait, then detaches after the first attach and immediately waits for the next one.

When you attach to a process in the SB API, you create an SBAttachInfo specifying what you want to attach to.  Be sure to call SetIgnoreExisting(True) on the second attach, that way it won't try to attach again to the first process. More details on writing Python based commands is here:

https://lldb.llvm.org/use/python-reference.html#create-a-new-lldb-command-using-a-python-function

And the API reference is here:

https://lldb.llvm.org/python_reference/index.html